# How to use VIM fold marks inside markdown?

Tags: vim, markdown, jekyll, liquid, folding

I like to stick to the default VIM foldind marks `{{{` and `}}}`, but creating some inside markdown make the liquid tag processor from jekyll go crazy, is there a way around to use them?

If not, what's a best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting you foldmarker inside of comments:

```
<!--- {{{ -->
content
<!--- }}} -->
```

Comment: Doesn't work in vim? (as it works for me) Or the jekyll is going crazzy?